# Does ServiceStack support Token based authentication?

Tags: oauth, servicestack, token

Asp.net Web api has out of the box support for token based authentication with minor configuration settings. I havent found anything like that for servicestack. Is there anyway how I can setup servicestack to provide tokens on authentication instead of session id.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack includes [support for JWT built-in](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) there are also a couple of other projects that enable token-based authentication with ServiceStack:

- [StatelessAuthentication](https://github.com/rvhelden/StatelessAuthentication)
- [Using IdentityServer 4 with ServiceStack and Angular](http://estynedwards.com/blog/2016/01/30/ServiceStack-IdentityServer-Angular/)
- [Auth0 ServiceStack Integration](https://auth0.com/docs/server-platforms/servicestack)
- [ServiceStack JWT Token validation for Auth0](https://gist.github.com/svantreeck/436f6ddddda38c735c62)